# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length() - laraval5

Tags: php, laravel-5, openssl

I'm building a Laravel application, It worked fine yesterday when I launched the server using

```
php artisan serve --port:8080
```

Due to some problem with wampserver for other applications I create, I had to delete it and install it again but still, my larval application worked fine.

Today when I started the server I got this error :

> FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to undefined function
>   Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

OpenSSL is activated in my PHP and I tried to run composter update but I got this error :

[image]

Can you help solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php artisan key:generate can solve cipher problem